# local copy of symfony /config/maps.json' is missing

Tags: php, symfony, wamp

I need to work on a site made with symfony, I downloaded directories, and files from live (working) site on my local environment, and when trying to access the site it gives me:
The json file 'path-to/htdocs/config/maps.json' is missing
I undesrtand I should change that somewhere as it should be;

```
/htdocs/SITE_NAME/config/maps.json
```

but where do I change that?
If you think there are some other path changes to be made, please suggest them.

Thank you

*EDIT to add sample of map.json*

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "request": "admin\/home",
            "controller": "Admin\/Index",
            "title": "Administration Panel",
            "injections": [],
            "tpl": "index.html.twig",
            "dependancies": [
                "Admin\/AdminLogin"
            ],
            "css": [
                "http:\/\/fonts.googleapis.com\/css?family=Molle:400italic",
                "http:\/\/fonts.googleapis.com\/css?family=Monda:700",
                "\/deployment\/css\/mods\/admin_mod\/admin.css",
                "\/deployment\/css\/mods\/admin_mod\/interface.css",
                "\/deployment\/css\/mods\/admin_mod\/admin-custom.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "\/js\/Vendors\/jquery-2.1.1.min.js",
                "\/js\/Vendors\/angular.min.js",
                "\/js\/modules\/ngUtils.js",
                "\/js\/Vendors\/ckeditor\/ckeditor.js",
                "\/js\/Vendors\/ngDialog.js",
                "\/js\/Mods\/Admin_mod\/definitions.js"
            ],
            "keywords": [
                "administration panel",
                "admin panel"
            ],
            "description": "Web site administration panel"
        },
        {
            "request": "admin\/logout",
            "controller": "Admin\/AdminLogin:logout",
            "injections": [
                "entityManager"
            ],
            "params": [],
            "dependancies": [],
            "css": [],
            "js": []
        },
        {
            "request": "",
            "controller": "",
            "injections": [],
            "dependancies": [],
            "params": [],
            "tpl": "",
            "css": [],
            "js": [],
            "title": "",
            "keywords": [],
            "description": []
        },
```

Comment: `maps.json` is not a standard file in Symfony, so it's specific to your application. We can't help you without more information about what is going on. Have you tried clearing the Symfony cache ?

Comment: Thank you. What kind of info would you need? I am not a coder, and first time I am interacting with symfony, how would I clear cache? That said I'd guess there is somewhere to tell it the path to maps.json though it is not standard?

Comment: Since I don't know what `maps.json` is and what your application wants to do with it, I don't know where to tell you to look. Maybe you could start searching in your entire source code for the name of the file and copy-pasting here what you find. Maybe that way we can start figuring things out.

Comment: Thank you. Not a single reference to map.json, but over 3700 words containing map, by a quick look they are like MAPpings, or sourceMappingURL=pagename.css.map. Anyhow I'll post a few lines of the map.json file.